# Need to install Python3 after installing anaconda3 and python2.7

Tags: python, anaconda

Currently, I have anaconda3 installed on my Mac, and I am using python 2.7 also. But I am trying to see if I can use python 3.1 as an alternative.

When I check the environments using the command,

```
conda info --envs
```

I get the output as :

```
base *  /anaconda3
python2 /anaconda3/envs/python2
```

MayI know what steps shd I take so that I can see `python3.1` also in list of environments? Do I need to reinstall anaconda3 on my machine.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres the files for python 3.1 download and install them https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.1/
This should make it appear if 3.1 is available with that software

Comment: Appreciate your response. Strangely enough when I run `condo info` in the terminal, I see the output as; `python version: 3.7.2.final.0`. Does it mean that already have python3 in my machine?Kindly advise.

Comment: Macs come pre-installed with python2 but there are some ways to instal python3, the one i said was the simplist can you confirm that its instaled probably by typing "python3" in the termnal p.s qote marks are not included in the command

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
conda install python=3.1
```